# Ocultar ou bloquear sab/dom do calendário

Tags: php, javascript, html

Olá, no meu formulário criei um calendário com a *tag* `input type=date` no meu `html`, **bloqueei os 3 dias a partir da data atual** e gostaria de **bloquear os sábados e domingos** para exibir **somente os dias úteis da semana**, alguém sabe como fazer ou tem alguma dica de como fazer?

Segue o que fiz até agora:

**Acrescenta 3 dias na data**

```php
$data = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+3 days', strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))));
```

**html simplificado**

```html
<input type="date" id="venc_via2" name="venc_via2" min="<?= $data; ?>">
```

Grato pela atenção.

Comment: Não se está usando algum framework, mas a maioria deles vem com uma função que busca os dias da semana (de 0 até 6), sendo 0-Domingo e 6-Sábado. Em JS ficaria parecido com essa resposta:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49863189/disable-weekends-on-html-5-input-type-date

Comment: @EdwardRamos obrigado, funcionou do jeito que eu quero.